# How can I make a virtual host accept multiple domains?

Tags: apache, apache2, apache-config

I have two different domains I want to use for this website, how can I configure the virtual host to make this work?

Is it possible to assign it more than one server name?

Comment: Setting configurations of the Apache web server is related to programming. This question should be reopened.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yes. Use the [`ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias) directive alongside the [`ServerName`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#servername) directive.

Comment: Great, thank you! For some reason i thought server alias only worked for local connections. 

Can I use several server aliases in a single server alias line?

If so, do I have to separate them by comas or just spaces?

Comment: @oalo: Yes, you can string together as many space-separated values as you like. Alternatively, you can have multiple `ServerAlias` lines.

Comment: This made it so I was able to use www.example.org and example.org in a browser. Thank you.